# after installing google map sdk failed to build project

Tags: ios, swift, api, google-maps, xcode11

I am integrating a Google Maps API. I have created a new project,  installed a Google Maps pod, opened `xcworkspace` and built a project. It is giving following error:

```
Ld /Users/nxgen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleMapTest2-dvqnpyvsumrrzbfpshbwaiyutzip/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleMapTest2.app/GoogleMapTest2 normal x86_64 (in target 'GoogleMapTest2' from project 'GoogleMapTest2')
    cd /Users/nxgen/Documents/GoogleMapTest2
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios13.7-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.7.sdk -L/Users/nxgen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleMapTest2-dvqnpyvsumrrzbfpshbwaiyutzip/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/nxgen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleMapTest2-dvqnpyvsumrrzbfpshbwaiyutzip/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/nxgen/Documents/GoogleMapTest2/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks -F/Users/nxgen/Documents/GoogleMapTest2/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks -filelist /Users/nxgen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleMapTest2-dvqnpyvsumrrzbfpshbwaiyutzip/Build/Intermediates.noindex/GoogleMapTest2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleMapTest2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GoogleMapTest2.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/nxgen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleMapTest2-dvqnpyvsumrrzbfpshbwaiyutzip/Build/Intermediates.noindex/GoogleMapTest2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleMapTest2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GoogleMapTest2_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/nxgen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleMapTest2-dvqnpyvsumrrzbfpshbwaiyutzip/Build/Intermediates.noindex/GoogleMapTest2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleMapTest2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GoogleMapTest2.swiftmodule -ObjC -lc++ -lz -framework Accelerate -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreText -framework GLKit -framework GoogleMaps -framework GoogleMapsBase -framework GoogleMapsCore -framework ImageIO -framework Metal -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/nxgen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleMapTest2-dvqnpyvsumrrzbfpshbwaiyutzip/Build/Intermediates.noindex/GoogleMapTest2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleMapTest2.build/GoogleMapTest2.app-Simulated.xcent -framework Pods_GoogleMapTest2 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nxgen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleMapTest2-dvqnpyvsumrrzbfpshbwaiyutzip/Build/Intermediates.noindex/GoogleMapTest2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleMapTest2.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GoogleMapTest2_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nxgen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleMapTest2-dvqnpyvsumrrzbfpshbwaiyutzip/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleMapTest2.app/GoogleMapTest2

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyNRNSA", referenced from:
      ___GMSCellNetworkTypeForRadioType_block_invoke in GoogleMaps
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyNR", referenced from:
      ___GMSCellNetworkTypeForRadioType_block_invoke in GoogleMaps
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Undefined symbol: _CTRadioAccessTechnologyNRNSA
Undefined symbol: _CTRadioAccessTechnologyNR
```

Can some one please help me to fix it?